Android emulation: how do I transfer data from a non functional virtual device to a new functioning one?
I am running the latest android studio on Apple silicon. I have a virtual device that won't turn on for reasons I cant figure out but the data is still in the correct directory (.android/avd/broken_avd)
I have created a new avd with the same hardware and api level as the previous one and it boots, it lives in .android/avd/new_avd (directory names not actual)
Is there a method to migrate the from broken_avd that won't turn on to new_avd?
When broken_avd was still working, I had managed to recover from errors by reloading a previous version of userdata-qemu.img.qcow2. But if I drop that in new_avd that doesn't work and new_avd just resets to default configurations
